# Why I cannot get values from SignalR Core in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, asp.net-core, frontend, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

This is my backend(.net core)=>

```
public async Task GetAllStocks() {
      await Clients.All.SendAsync("OnAllStocks", _stockTicker.GetAllStocks());
}
```

This is my frontend(flutter) =>

```
HubConnection? hubConn;
List<Object>? a;

startHubConn() {
    hubConn = HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('http://192.168.1.115:2308/stockTickerHub').build();
    hubConn!.on('OnAllStocks',(arguments) => {
      debugPrint('count: '+arguments!.length.toString()),
      a = arguments
    });
    hubConn!.start();
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you debug the code and check if it hits the `GetAllStocks` method? Did you also check what's the result of `_stockTicker.GetAllStocks()`?

Comment: Same result @Rena